# Create new item in sharepoint when a new record is created in salesforce

Tags: development, api

Newbie here to both Sharepoint and Salesforce. I have a customer that needs to get data automatically put into Sharepoint when a new order is created in Salesforce. Does anyone have an example of how to do this using api calls or other code?

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way to achieve this is using Flow, you can use the premium triggers provided out of the box to write a flow which can do this for you.

[image: salesforce trigger]

**OR**

Second way is to follow below steps:

- **Step 1:** Authentication request is sent to the adapter by Salesforce.
- **Step 2:** The adapter forwards the request to SharePoint.
- **Step 3:** After authenticating the information, SharePoint passes the security token for further use.
- **Step 4:** The adapter receives the token and thereafter sends it to Salesforce.
- **Step 5:** The token is used as an authentication key, Salesforce then send a request to view the accessible files and folders.
- **Step 6:** The Adapter then forwards the request along with the token and subsequently receives an output. It then again passes on to the Salesforce installation.
- **Step 7:** Either of the two things happen: First being either the token expires and the process is repeated again or secondly using the same token, more requests are sent and received.

for more details about it [check here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000fzfWIAQ)

Comment: Thank you guys. We won't be using Flow so I'll have to go with the second option. All of those steps can be completed using api calls for both sharepoint and salesforce?